# How to install LAMP-package+Netbeans in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, netbeans, lamp

I'm new in Ubuntu (12.04), and I'm trying to install LAMP-package for developing:
1) Typed the following command "sudo tasksel install lamp-server". All is OK.
2) Installed full Netbeans IDE. Created a new PHP project. Executed this project and got the following message:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /TestPhpProject/index.php was not found on this server.

Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

URL for it: `http://localhost/TestPhpProject/index.php`

So, please, tell me, how can I test my applications in Netbeans? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you put your files in the /var/www folder?

Your Apache server is up and running however your project can't be found.

Comment: I'm trying to put a new project into /var/www folder, but Netbeans shows the following message "You can't put files into this folder". What does it mean?

Comment: Check the permissions; you have to have write permissions to the /var/www folder.

Comment: sudo chown your_user_name /var/www/project_folder_name